# Error when re-presenting view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I present a modal view controller in which the user can enter some information, then upon saving that information with this function...

```
func handleSave() {

    guard let newProductUrl = NSURL(string: urlTextField.text!) else {
        print("error getting text from product url field")
        return
    }
    guard let newProductName = self.nameTextField.text else {
        print("error getting text from product name field")
        return
    }
    guard let newProductImage = self.logoTextField.text else {
        print("error getting text from product logo field")
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.productController?.save(name: newProductName, url: newProductUrl as URL, image: newProductImage)
    }


    // Present reloaded view controller with new product added
    let ac = UINavigationController()
    let pController = ProductController()
    productController = pController
    ac.viewControllers = [pController]
    present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

... I get an error in the `viewWillAppear` of `ProductController` (the controller that presented the modal view controller, and now am trying to get back to)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let companyToDisplay = self.navigationItem.title!

    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Product")

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"company.name == %@",companyToDisplay)

    do {
        products = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        print(products)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

The error is: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional, on the line `let companyToDisplay = self.navigationItem.title!`. How do I specify that the `self.navigationItem.title` that it's looking for (and missing) is the `self.navigationItem.title` of the controller that sent the modal view?

Thanks for any help, I've been trying to sort this problem out for days and can't figure it out.

EDIT: This is how I present the modal view `AddProductController` from my `ProductController`

```
func presentModalView() {

    let nc = UINavigationController()
    let addProductController = AddProductController()
    nc.viewControllers = [addProductController]

    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
    self.present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

EDIT: Putting code inside dispatch block:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.productController?.save(name: newProductName, url: newProductUrl, image: newProductImage)

        let pController = ProductController()
        self.productController = pController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pController, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem, you used present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil) to get to this view, so this presentation is modal and there is no navigationController.
You have to use UINavigationController.pushViewController to present the view and this way you will get the navigationController.

Edit:

```
        let nc = UINavigationController()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let addProductController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addProductVC")
    nc.viewControllers = [addProductController]

    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
    self.present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Just don't forget to set the identifier for the addProductController in storyboard, change the storyboard and VC identifier to your ones.

Edit 2 :

```
            let nc = UINavigationController()
    let addProductController = ProductController()
    addProductController.navigationItem.title = "Have a good one"
    nc.viewControllers = [addProductController]

    self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
    self.present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I've changed it to `ac.pushViewController(pController, animated: true)` and am now getting a crash with error: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported'

Comment: You should not just change one thing in your code, change ac to UINavigationController, if it didn't work, please tell me to edit my post and put the complete code

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking - `UINavigationController.pushViewController(pController, animated: true)` does not work.

Comment: Just edited my post to your code, I tested it, this worked for me and showed the second VC in a nav bar, is that what you needed?

Comment: I'll try it out but I'm not using storyboard, this is all programmatic so I don't know how to set the identifiers

Comment: This presents a new view controller, I'm trying to return to the table view `ProductController`that the modal view was sent from, with the `ProductController` tableview updated to include the new product that the user has entered in the modal view

Comment: For getting back you should call dismiss from the second VC, and call delegate before that to send back the data

Comment: I haven't learned delegates yet, I'm not sure how to do that. But it's looking like that's what it will have to be.

Comment: I am at work right now, will edit my answer to use delegates soon

Comment: Mohsen did you get a chance to figure out how to do this with delegates? I'd love to see how it's done!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the block inside this call:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.productController?.save(name: newProductName, url: newProductUrl as URL, image: newProductImage)
}
```

actually executes *after* your `handleSave()` method returns.  Looks like you're expecting it to execute sequentially with respect to the other code in that method.

`DispathQueue.main.async` adds a block to a queue of code to be executed at some point in the future -- it doesn't execute immediately.

To fix this, you need to put code *inside* the dispatch block which does whatever needs to happen next.  This would be similar to what you have here:

```
// Present reloaded view controller with new product added
let ac = UINavigationController()
let pController = ProductController()
productController = pController
ac.viewControllers = [pController]
present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But you probably want to clean up how/where you're creating and dismissing view controllers -- what you have here looks like it will unnecessarily pile up a bunch of view controllers.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm having trouble with.. I tried putting the code inside the dispatch block but still got the same error mentioned in my question. I edited my question to show to new code that I tried (still getting used to navigating around views, and core data, so please let me know if there's a better way to do it)

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do without looking at all the code, but try reframing the problem so you only use one instance of ProductController.  It doesn't look like you need to create a new one each time you save something.

Comment: I know, sorry this is a big learning project for me and I'm getting lost in the view controller/navigation controllers. I thought I did only have one instance of ProductController, then the modal view `AddProductController`. I'm really confused to can't really explain properly... This is the project if you want to see the error (tap edit ->done->tap a company and try to add a product to see the error): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17411581/NavCtrl.zip

Comment: Have you tried implementing this using storyboards?  That's usually how apps like this are put together.  Using a storyboard will probably help you structure things in a way which will avoid the errors you're having.

Comment: I'd like to get it done without storyboards, I'd really have to start the whole project over if I wanted to use storyboard, and I've been working on this for over a month and it's really just this particular issue that's holding me back from completing it.

Comment: The general problem is passing data between view controllers.  Try reading some of the SO questions about that (like, search for "ios pass data between view controllers).  I think you'll find similar examples in those threads.  Good luck!